# How to calculate median and mode from continuous data?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

If data is continuous (not discrete) how to calculate **median** and **mode**?

Comment: The rule (or convention) for calculating the median of continuous data is exactly the same for continuous and discrete data that can be ordered: Sort values on the variable in question from smallest to largest. Then if the number of values is odd, the median is the middlemost value; and if it is even, the mean of the two middlemost values (sometimes called "comedians").  The question of how to get at estimates of the mode for continuous data is good and deeper, but already discussed on CV.

Comment: tnx for your answer.